# meta tags shows in <body> While Should be placed in the <head>

Tags: python, html, django

I have a website based on the django framework. I want to add meta tags to the website With conditions :

```
"""Definition of models."""

from django.db import models

class Pages_Meta(models.Model):
      Page_name = models.TextField(null=False)
      Page_meta  = models.TextField(null=False)
      page_title = models.TextField(null=False)
```

And html page is:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title> {{ title }} - Farhad Dorod  </title>
       {{ meta }}
   </head>
</html>
<body>  ...  </body>
```

And urls.py is:

```
path('index/',
     LoginView.as_view(
         template_name='app/index.html',
         extra_context=
         {
             'title': Pages_Meta.objects.get(id = 1).page_title,
             'meta' : Pages_Meta.objects.get(id = 1).Page_meta,
         }),
     name='index')
```

result: all meta tags shows in **body** While Should be placed in the **head**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Django's template tag `safe` you can approve the content as html safe, allowing it to render as html. Like so:

```html
{{ meta|safe }}
```